# Download iOS alarm tones

Tags: ios, itunes, music, android

I have an iPad Air 2 running iOS 11 and an Android phone. Now, I want to be able to access the alarm tones from the iPad on the Android phone (I find them to be more soothing). Is there an easy way to go about transferring them?

I could not figure out how to do it via iTunes (assuming there is a way).

The android phone is running Oreo (if that is of any relevance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides no easy transfer mechanism for embedded alarm tones from iPad to another device. The things you are expected to transfer are exposed for syncing via iTunes. The audio files are proprietary and are not user accessible or even licensed for this.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to appropriate those sounds would be to record the headphone / line out on a computer or android or iOS. Whichever recording tool you prefer should be able to record with more fidelity than you’ll need for output with a bonus of having the sounds encoded in the format easiest for you to use on Android os.

Comment: Also, consider just making your own soothing sounds. If you can learn how Apple's sound design is done and then adapt and create, you have a much better skill than simply copying, but as long as you don’t sell or distribute the sounds verbatim, you’re less likely to run into legal or moral trouble.